# Error loading preloads: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module:

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

While running Jupyter notebook cells on VS Code, it throws this error

```
Error loading preloads: 

 -  Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-webview.net/c%3A/Users/Acer/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.9.1101343141/out/datascience-ui/errorRenderer/errorRenderer.js
```

It worked fine earlier but somehow it's throwing errors now and not showing the error from notebooks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139545)

Answer (score 8):

The culprit is Jupyter Notebook Renderers extension v 1.0.4.....rolling back v 1.0.3 solves the issue.

Comment: To roll back go to Extensions panel, find Jupyter Notebook Renderers and choose "Install other version" option.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Jupyter using Anaconda for my current environment, opened it once, and then I was able to use that environment in VS Code. Before I did that, I got that error in VS Code using the Jupyter plug in, set to the correct environment. I did not update or revert any extensions in VS Code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got this error after installing Jupyter Notebook Renderers to VS code

```
Error loading renderer 'vscode.builtin-renderer' Failed to fetch dynamically 
imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/d%3A/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/extensions/notebook-renderers/renderer-out/index.js
```

I restarted my VS Code to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this issue you Restart your vs code

Comment: This was already proposed in a [much earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73468731/10871073). Please check other answers before posting your own.